# Taxonomy List in node/add Capitalize all letters in the parent only

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a strange customer request for a taxonomy list users select from while adding content.

[image]

The request from the customer is have the parent vid show up in ALL CAPS and the children to be left alone.

What's the best approach to this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hook_form_alter to alter the node form. This way you don't alter the data in the vocabulary.

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // For 'article' content type.
  if ($form_id === 'article_node_form') {
    $lang_code = $form['language']['#value'];
    foreach ($form['field_dd'][$lang_code]['#options'] as $key => $value) {
      // Check if option starts with '-' sign. Only child starts with '-' sign.
      // If yes, then continue.
      if (strpos($value, '-') === 0) {
        continue;
      }
      // Else capitalize all the characters.
      $form['field_dd'][$lang_code]['#options'][$key] = strtoupper($value);
      // $form['field_dd'][$lang_code]['#options'][$key]['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('option-blue'));
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Hope this is what you expected.]

**Note:**

Refer this link for your new use case: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes

Comment: If I wanted to add a span tag to the code above what would be the best approach?  I tried `'<span style="color:blue">'.strtoupper($value).'</span>'` but when rendered it converts them to html entities.

Comment: have update the answer. the best approach, as per me, would be to use `attributes` to add a class and then, update the css for that class.

Comment: Since this is new I've created a new question here:  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198524/add-a-class-to-parent-taxonomy-terms-only.